# Is there a tool to convert a Buckminster project into Maven?

Tags: maven, buckminster

I'm tasked with migrating our product's build/dependency-management technology from Buckminster to Maven.  I'm quite decent with Maven, but before I drill down into Buckminster's inner-workings (which I'm not currently very knowledgeable on), I thought I'd see if there was an available tool to automate this, as it would be a rather lengthy task if done manually.  If not, I guess I'll write one myself.

Any input would be much appreciated!  Thanks!